# Is there a working Quarkus OpenTelemetry support in reactive Mutiny code?

Tags: quarkus, open-telemetry, mutiny

I'm trying to introduce OpenTelemetry into our existing Quarkus-based (v 2.9.2.final) set of services.
All services are written in a reactive way based on Mutiny.
I'm failing to continue Spans or add events and attributes to them.
I have configured Quarkus to produce traces into a locally running Otel collector with Zipkin and Jaeger.

Observations:

- Quarkus creates Spans for every incoming REST request. I can add attributes here. Such span gets reported into Jaeger.
- If I use `@WithSpan` annotation on a reactive method somewhere downstream  - this span gets reported but without the link to the parent span created in the REST API
- If I do not annotate the downstream reactive method and try to access and amend `Span.current()`  I'm provided with the span created in the REST API abut any attribute or event addition is not propagated to Jaeger
- If I try to inject OpenTelemetry `Context` bean - there is no such

Is there any working Quarkus OpenTelemetry reactive code sample?
Or does Quarkus support OpenTelemetry just partially in non-reactive code?

Comment: Did you get it working? I have the same problem!

Comment: Nope, I'm still waiting for the Quarkus team to implement proper trace context handling and propagation along the reactive pipelines and some sort of documentation or examples :-(

Comment: This issue is reported here in Quarkus Github repository : https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/25453. I hope it will fixed someday.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found an inspiration in this Quarkus [Superheroes demo](https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-superheroes-to-the-rescue/) - in the `io.quarkus.sample.superheroes.statistics.listener.SuperStats` class.

I tried to adapt it to be used with CosmosDB change feed processor and to also bridge Mutiny -> Reactor pipelines.
I ended up with the helper [Tracer](https://github.com/jan-peremsky/quarkus-reactive-otel/blob/c74043d388ec4df155f466f1d6938931c3389b70/src/main/java/com/fng/ewallet/pex/Tracer.java) class. It might help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).